# Is it Heroku postgresql database free for hobby package? If yes, How much data can store it?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I have a web app which contains a PostgreSQL database. I want to host my site in Heroku hobby package. But I bit confuse the pricing policy of Heroku. I don't sure that Heroku hobby package includes PostgreSQL freely. If freely connect the PostgreSQL database in a hobby package, then my question how much data can I store freely?

Comment: I don't think this question is about programming, but rather pricing of a product, so it's probably off-topic here. Nevertheless, here's the [link to Heroku's pricing for Postgres](https://www.heroku.com/pricing#postgres-pricing) where it states that if you want 10K rows, it's $0, otherwise $9 for 10M rows, with some far more expensive tiers also available.

Comment: Thanks for your replay!